# SQL for three sequential items

Tags: sql, hive, time-series, bigdata

I have a table with events like `(EVENT_ID, TIMESTAMP, EVENT_NAME, EVENT_SCORE)`

I want to make a table like  `(EVENT_ID1, EVENT_ID2, EVENT_ID3,  EVENT_NAME, EVENT_SCORE1, EVENT_SCORE2, EVENT_SCORE3)` where each row corresponds to three events, where

- TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID1 is less than TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID2,
- TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID2 is less than TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID3
- TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID1 is within an hour of TIMESTAMP for EVENT_ID3
- EVENT_NAME is the same for all 3 events in a row
- EVENT_ID1 & EVENT_ID3 have EVENT_SCORE > 0.9
- EVENT_ID2 has an EVENT_SCORE > 0.8
- (EVENT_ID, EVENT_NAME) is distinct

How would I write this query?     I'm doing this in HIVE if that matters.

Some sample data

```
event_id   timestamp   event_name  event_score
1          3000        alarm       0.95  
10         3500        alarm       0.85
7          3700        noise       0.96
5          4000        alarm       0.93
20         4200        alarm       0.87
30         5000        alarm       0.87
30         8000        alarm       0.97

event_id1   event_id2   event_id3   event_name  event_score1   event_score2   event_score3
1           10          5           alarm       0.95           0.85            0.93
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: yeah, sample up above.     i'm sure i'm missing some detail -- basically want sequential events with the same event_name where the event boxed in is just below some threshhold.    above,  event2 would basically be an alarm that *almost* went off

Comment: Since you have no answers yet, I'll try to help. Here is a fiddle with an answer, but I'm not confident it would be correct in all cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef07/4